# Mesos agent not appear as mesos agent in the UI

Tags: mesos

I've recently added a new **mesos agent** in my cluster. It appears in the *web ui* but if I go to the agents tab I see that in the Agent attribute is showing a master machine and in the Master attribute is not showing anything and furthermore the Resources section is empty.

Any help please,

thanks.

[image: Mesos Web UI]

Comment: If you can put your code, we can help you much better

Comment: added a screenshot, msm1 is one of the masters. Should I restart the masters or the slaves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think that is not an error. When you do not have any framework running in your agent this info is normal.

thanks anyway for you interest.